# no "demos" file in KivyMD folder, using bash terminal

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

using bash terminal, there is no "demos" file in KivyMD folder

there has ben said if I install older versions of kivy(such as 2.0.0) there will be a "demos" file but program doesnt let me to install the older versions either
and why the latest versions doesnt work? how do these people use it then if we should install older version of kivy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the kivy-examples package using:

```
python -m pip install kivy-examples
```

If you are using a virtual environment, the examples will be in:
`virtual env directory/share/kivy-examples`
and the demo programs will be in the 'demo' directory under that.

If you are using the system python install, then it will be in the systems `/usr/share/kivy-examples` directory.